# Converting hexstring to byte array in java and python

Tags: java, python

Here is sample code that I tried for conversion in java and python. I am new to this concept. Why am I getting different value? How can I get the same value that I got in java in python?

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
output :[B@57829d67
In python I tried:
test = bytearray.fromhex("4BE7C580")
output : bytearray(b'K\xe7\xc5\x80')
```

Comment: Did you try to just print an array in Java? You have to print each individual element, otherwise it will just give the data type and memory address.

Comment: @SamCraig yes i did.

Comment: java out is wrong ! hex string already contained byte values, From the end to the beginning the byte value is two characters.(Add zero if the item is a single digit per length) **I don't understand what that function is.**

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] array = hexStringToByteArray("4BE7C580");
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    for (byte b : array) {
        System.err.println(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
    }
}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

gives

```
[75, -25, -59, -128]
4b
e7
c5
80
```